# Nginx case sensitive return

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am using a subdomain to redirect to an external domain with a case sensitive URL (for me, a Google form).

I want to go from `short.mydomain.com` -> `externaldomain.com/ReallyLongAndCaseSensitiveUrl`

I have implemented a redirect using Ngnix and it redirects the user, however the URL becomes entirely lowercase which creates an invalid link (it redirects the user to `externaldomain.com/reallylongandcasensitiveeurl`).

How do I make it so the redirect maintains its casing?

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name .short.mydomain.com;
        return 302 https://externaldomain.com/ReallyLongAndCaseSensitiveUrl;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think Nginx is doing this. You can confirm this using `curl -I http://short.mydomain.com` and checking the value of the `Location` header in the response.

Comment: Can confirm this is Google Chrome related (how ironic as I am trying to redirect to a Google Form). This issue does not exist in Firefox... Hmmm.... Thank you @RichardSmith

Comment: Okay, I found a solution that works.... But I can't really explain it.
The issue relates to Google Chrome. It is not an issue in Firefox or when using curl.
I found someone having a similar issue with Chrome redirects, they added a '/' to the end of the URL and Chrome now respected the cases. However, this doesnt work for me as it break the link to the form. Instead I added '?usp=sf_link' to the end and Chrome now respects the casing.

I am trying to find a more complete solution, but as this is a quick and dirty hack for me, I might just leave it like this.